# Need help understanding pointers and various other C stuff

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct dict_pair {
  void *key;
  void *value;
  struct dict_pair *tail;
} dict;


dict* NewDictionary(void) {
  dict *dictionary = malloc(sizeof(dict)); //or we can malloc(sizeof(struct dict_pair))
  dictionary->tail = NULL;
}

//dict operations
void put(dict *dictionary, void *key, void *value) {
  //new pair
  dict *new_pair = malloc(sizeof(dict));
  new_pair->key = key;
  new_pair->value = value;
  //chaining
  new_pair->tail = NULL;
  dict *last_node = dictionary;
  while (last_node->tail != NULL) {
    last_node = last_node->tail;
  }

  last_node->tail = new_pair;
}

void* get(dict *dictionary, void *key) {
  dict *current_dict = dictionary;
  while (1) {
    if (current_dict->key == key) {
      return current_dict->value;
    }
    else if (dictionary->tail != NULL) {
      current_dict = current_dict->tail;
    } else break;
  }
  return NULL;
}
//end operations

int main(void) {
  dict *dictionary = NewDictionary();
  put(dictionary,(void *) "buffer1",(void *) "Fake1");
  put(dictionary,(void *) "buffer2",(void *) "Fake2");
  put(dictionary,(void *) "key",(void *) "This is the value.");
  char *result = (char *) get(dictionary, (void *) "key");
  printf("%s\n",result);
}
```

So I managed to write the above code to implement a dictionary. While I was able to write the code and compile and get it to work expectedly, there are some stuff which I am not clear about. Mostly regarding pointers:

```
dict *current_dict = dictionary;
```

Lets take this line for example. We are declaring a variable which holds dict type. current_dict is a pointer, right? and dictionary is a pointer. However, *current_dict is not a pointer, how can it be assigned to a pointer?

Or do I have to explicitly type this to make it error?

```
dict (*current_dict) = dictionary;
```

If so, would this mean that the above line mean that we are declaring a current_dict variable with a dict type, and it is a pointer. Wouldnt that declaration be

```
(dict*) current_dict = dictionary;
```

As you can see, the spacing and positioning is confusing me.

Can someone help with explaining the difference in the * positioning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While `dict *dictionary` and `dict* dictionary` have the same meaning in C, I prefer the former.

I prefer to think of pointer declarations in these terms:

```
int   x; //  x is an int
int  *y; // *y is an int
int **z; //**z is an int
```

If you remember that `*y` is the object that `y` points to, then it follows that `y` must be a pointer-to-an-int. And similarly `z` must be a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-an-int.

Answer (score 4):

When you write:

```
dict * current_dict = dictionary;
```

this is equivalent to:

```
dict * current_dict;
current_dict = dictionary;
```

I understand your confusion, because `*` is used for two purposes in the C language:  One purpose is to declare a pointer in a declaration.  The second purpose is to dereference a pointer in an expression.

Your example is a declaration on the left side of the equal sign and an expression on the right side of the equal sign.  (Technically it's all a declaration which contains an expression, but that muddies the point of why `*` means a particular thing in a particular context.)

Answer (score 2):

```
// * to the right of a type means a pointer of that type
Dict* dictPtr1 = dictPtr2; // LHS and RHS are pointers
Dict* dictPtr4 = (Dict *) malloc( sizeof(Dict));

// * to the left of a variable means dereference that variable
// the variable must be a pointer
Dict dictObject = *dictPtr; // LHS and RHS are objects


// & to the left of a variable means the address-of the object
Dict* dictPtr3 = &dictObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where * stands in a variable declaration. `dict* current` and `dict *current` are the same. But if you use a pointer in an expression then `*dict` means dereferencing, that is, it returns an object pointed by `dict`.

Comment: This is not perfectly accurate. It does matter where the * stands, if you declare multiple variables in a single statement. So dict* current, other would create two pointers to dict, where dict *current, other would create one pointer and one variable containing the struct.

Comment: I don't think it is true. dict *current, other still declares a pointer and a value. dict *current, *other declare two pointers.

Comment: I just checked it and you are right. I was sure dict* current, other; would create two pointers, but gcc proved me wrong. Sorry for the misinformation!

Answer (score 1):

```
dict *current_dict;
```

is a pointer, whitespace is not significant here.
All these definitions are similar:

```
dict *current_dict;
dict* current_dict;
dict * current_dict;
dict*current_dict;
```

In all the above cases, **current_dict** is of type **pointer to dict**

Be aware, if you have something like this:

```
dict * current_dict,other_dict;
```

You have declared 2 variables; **current_dict** is of type **pointer to dict** while **other_dict** is of type **dict**

Answer (score 0):

> `dict *current_dict = dictionary;`
>
> Lets take this line for example. We
>   are declaring a variable which holds
>   dict type. current_dict is a pointer,
>   right? and dictionary is a pointer.
>   However, *current_dict is not a
>   pointer, how can it be assigned to a
>   pointer?

This declares `current_dict` to be a pointer to a `dict` and sets it to point to the same place that `dictionary` points to. The positioning of * is only relevant when you declare multiple variables on the same line.

Had you put

```
dict current_dict = dictionary;
```

this would not have worked correctly because this declares `current_dict` to be the actual struct.

For what it's worth, in your put function there is no reason to do

```
dict *last_node = dictionary;
```

and then use last_node rather than `dictionary`. They are both pointers to the same thing and when you declare a pointer in your function parameters as you did with `dict *dictionary` your function is actually getting a local copy of the pointer from the calling function. Changes to the local copy of the pointer in `dictionary` will not affect the pointer in the calling function (if you wanted such a thing you'd need to have a function declaration like `void put(dict **dictionary, void *key, void *value)`... but you don't want that here. :) ).